# Java multiple selection dialog box

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, joptionpane, dialog

I have a dialog box with a drop down menu like this:

```
Object[] possibilities = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/middle.gif");
int i = Integer.parseInt((String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(pane,"How Many Channels:","Reset Visible Channels",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,icon,possibilities,"1"));
```

The problem is that it only lets you select one option.  Instead, I would like 
for users to be able to select multiple options from a list that is given in 
the dialog box.  Something like the following:

```
Object[] possibilities = {"apples", "oranges", "lemons", "grapes"};
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("images/middle.gif");
String s = (String)what do i put here instead of JOptionPane.showInputDialog();  ?
```

Can anyone show me how to alter this code so that it does what I am asking?

It would be nice to know what some of my various format options are.  And I would really appreciate any links to some good articles on the topic.  The articles I have found from my google searches are not very informative.  I might be using the wrong key words.

Comment: *"Can anyone show me how to alter this code so that it does what I am asking?"*  Can you post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`JList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) is also a good alternative for multiple selections.

Comment: Thank you.  I carefully read through the article you linked to.  I will be experimenting with that code today, along with the link mKorbel sent.  I may or may not have follow up questions later.

Comment: I ended up rolling my own.  But since I used a JList in my version, I am marking your answer as correct.  Thank you.  +1 for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest a JTable with 2 columns. The first one is Boolean class based and the second one is text for the boolean.

Comment: +1 btw, for `JTable`. This this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table) may be a little overkill for your use case, but it shows the render/edit flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

you probably needed [JCheckBox or JRadioButton](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox) tutorial shows similair example as you ...

Comment: Are you saying I should have a new JFrame pop up with check boxes and a submit button?  Essentially rolling my own dialog box?  Perhaps this is why nothing was coming up on my google searches.

Comment: maybe not JFrame but own with JDialog#setModal(true); (then block all output out of JDialog except ALT+F4) and if you'll re-use that for another Actions, then JDialog#setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: This is the straighforward approach.

Comment: last two weeks somebody sits on my cable to the..., please could you be little bit concrete

Comment: Sorry, I meant that `JCheckBox` is a common way to indicate multiple selection. Sits? Cable?

Comment: @mKorbel Yes, I ended up extending JDialog.  Thanks for the suggestion. +1 for your help.